# How to get all checked out files in SharePoint client object model c#?

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, caml-query

I need to get all checked out files from a document library. I am trying by following query.

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @
"<View>
       <Query>
              <Where>
                <IsNotNull>
                    <FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser' />
                </IsNotNull>
              </Where>
         </Query>
 </View>";
```

Above query returns the documents those are checked out by current user. I need to get all checked out documents (checked out by any use).

**update**

I have required columns. When users drag and drop files without filling out those columns it's remain invisible to others. Whenever users upload document, it goes to the **Manage files which have no checked in version**. I need to get those files grammatically.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
<Where>
   <IsNotNull>
       <FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser' />                                            
   </IsNotNull>
</Where>
```

with

```
<Where>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser" LookupId="TRUE" />
              <Value Type="int">0</Value>
    </Geq>
</Where>
```

Comment: The CAML Query is definitely working. You can check using U2U CAML Query builder on your site.

Comment: Ya I did that already... Not working in U2U as well as CSOM. Did you test it?

Comment: I responded to your comment just after testing it. Infact, I will take back my original answer as <IsNotNull> works as well.

Comment: I my library I have three documents. Two of them are checked out by another user and last one is by current user. This code shows only one document when I run as current user and shows two document when I run as other user. Actually I need three document whoever the user is. Is it the scenario for you?

Comment: <IsNotNull>  or your query shows the documents of current user only. Not of all users

Comment: Please let me know you last feedback....... I am following

Comment: The CAML query on U2U is returning the result for all users..I just checked this as well.

Comment: <Query>
   <Where>
      <Geq>
         <FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser" LookupId="TRUE" />
         <Value Type="int">0</Value>
      </Geq>
   </Where>
</Query>

Comment: Is not working for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26856/discussion-between-ransher-singh-and-atish-dipongkor).

Comment: I have required columns. When users drag and drop files without filling out those columns it's remain invisible to others. This is issue in my case. Your answer is 100% right without required columns. Any idea about required columns

Comment: That's great. I don't have an answer for you at the moment so I would advise that you update the original question with this information so that someone who knows might be able to help you.

Comment: @AtishDipongkor you can set a filter in view. If specified field is not null, then only its visible to user.

Comment: I think CSOM doesn't support getting checked-out documents even if you are using SCA account. I did test it with getting draft versions and it wont work